# Is programmers the appropriate website to ask about system design questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, design-review

Note: This is a follow-up question to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290723/is-stack-overflow-the-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-system-design-questions) one.

I'm planning to practice some system design questions asked during tech interviews, and I'd like to get reviews/opinions on how I'd design some systems from the Programmers/StackExchange community if I can.

Can I post these questions on Programmers, or would some other StackExchange site be more appropriate for this?

Comment: We had a previous discussion about if [design reviews were on-topic or not](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/design-review-on-topic-or-not). They would be on-topic, but can very easily cross into primarily opinion based or too broad if insufficient constraints are placed on the design or if the question is not about a particular aspect of a design. Could you elaborate with specific examples (one or two, perhaps) of the questions that you are thinking about asking?